# Guidelines for choosing integrand to get a sum.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

[image]

The idea was to find:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(n\pi)}{n^3}$$

As you see in the solution, they conveniently choose a $f(z)$ they chose:

$$f(z) = \frac{\pi \cot(\pi z)\coth(\pi z)}{z^3}$$

That eventually led to their goal.

**What are the guidelines for choosing such $f(z)$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i'm not an expert in this kind of problems, but i think you should have always three things in mind:

1.) Some of the poles of your generating function should render the sum that you are looking for

2.) The residues of all the other poles should be:

2a) As Easily obtainable as possible and 
 2b) be of finite number, or generating a sum which is easier to calculate then   original one.

3.) You have to make sure that you can close your contour of integration in an appropriate manner

I hope this helps...

Comment: In (2) shouldnt there be infinite poles? For which we get the same residue?

Comment: no, in 1.) we generate our sum, in 2.) we make sure that our problem reduces in complexity, which is achieved (most of the times) in an effective manner if we just have a finite number of terms to add up.